# Move elements in a multidimensional array.

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array with parents and childs and i want to change the array keys

It looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 108
        [parent_id] => 0
        [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                 [id] => 71
                 [parent_id] => 108
                 [children] => Array
                 (
                     [0] => stdClass Object
                     (
                         [id] => 107
                         [parent_id] => 71
                         [children] => Array
                         (
                             [0] => stdClass Object
                             (
                                 [id] => 78
                                 [parent_id] => 107
                             )
                         )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )

    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 82
        [parent_id] => 0
    )

    [2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 84
        [parent_id] => 0
    )

    [3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 88
        [parent_id] => 0
    )

    [4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 92
        [parent_id] => 0
    )
)
```

I want to move, for example, the array with the id 108 below the array [id] => 88. The problem is to move an array to a new position but moving also the child arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
function array_remove($array, $index) {
    array_splice($array, $index, 1, array());
    return $array;
}

function array_insert($array, $element, $index) {
    array_splice($array, $index, 0, array($element));
    return $array;
}

function array_move($array, $from, $to) {
    $element = $array[$from];
    $array = array_remove($array, $from);
    $array = array_insert($array, $element, $to - 1);
    return $array;
}

$array = array_move($array, 0, 4);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: thank you Alin but there's a bit of a problem, the array never gets inserted. so if you have array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8); and i move 0 to 6 i get Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
) but the value 6 it's lost.. so i want to move the key and it's values

Comment: i think i solved this is what i have modif array_splice($array, $to, 0 ,$array[$to]); on function array_move before the array_remove call