# Move element of array to deepest match - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need to convert this structure:

```
a : {
    b : {}
},
c : {
    d : {},
    e : {}
},
b : {
    c : {}
}
```

I need to get the order into:

```
a : {
    b : {
        c : {
            d : {},
            e : {}
        }
    }
},
...
```

I am trying to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951599/move-elements-in-a-multidimensional-array) but that doesnt seem to move elements up and down the levels of the object.

It needs to be appended on to the deepest level (so if `c` was under `d` and not `b`, it must append there and not under `b`.

What is the best way to do this?